# Shopify : Errors: [API] This action requires merchant approval for write_themes scope

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am new to Shopify and I'm trying to setup Shopify themekit locally.

I have created an private app and setup my store, but while trying to access store using theme kit I get this error:

`Errors: [API] This action requires merchant approval for write_themes scope.`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Private apps have limited permissions like public apps do. You can fix your app's permissions by opening [the private apps section](https://myshopify.com/admin/apps/private) of the admin and tapping on the name of your app.

Scroll down to the section labelled `ADMIN API PERMISSIONS` and tap on `▼ Review disabled Admin API permissions`. Set `Theme templates and theme assets` to `Read and write` and then save and it should work.

Comment: It's worth noting this has to be done on the *merchant* site, not the partners site.

Comment: Any ideas why I can't change any items from "ADMIN API PERMISSIONS" section even when logged in as Admin?

Answer (score 8):

### The year 2023 answer

Go to your shop admin website
[https://admin.shopify.com/store/{your-website-name}](https://admin.shopify.com/store/%7Byour-website-name%7D)

Go to `Settings` (bottom left corner) -> `Apps and sales channels` -> `Develop apps` -> [select your app] -> `Configuration` tab -> Edit `Admin API integration` -> search for the desired scope.

FYI: Private apps were discontinued, and are now called Custom apps.

Answer (score 1):

After going into Settings > Apps & Channels, you need to click on 'Develop Apps' button, and then select the related app to access the API settings.

This error may occur for any number of permissions (though the OP asked about 'write_themes' scope).

Errors: [API] This action requires merchant approval for {PERMISSION} scope.

{PERMISSION} may be any number of the listed API permissions.  Those without access are now listed under 'Inactive' (vs. 'Disabled').
Search for the permission most closely related to the one listed in your error:
e.g. "errors": [api] this action requires merchant approval for read_content scope. is related to "Store Content" permission = Read.

It's also worth checking that your webhook API version is aligned between the Shopify App config and your private app.

Once you've made your edits and save, you'll be asked to confirm that you want to edit these settings.  This is just to make sure you understand what within your store you are giving the app access to; if you are good with the implications, approve and submit and retry the API call from your private app.