# Getting empty product list in Shopify Admin API in postman

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm new to Shopify App Development and trying to perform CRUD operation with API.

Below is the URL that i am sending in postman to see list of products in Shopify Store.

`https:{api_key}:{api_token}@operation-crud-app.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/products.json`

I have remove the api_*token*_key for security purpose.

The output of the url is

```
PS D:\Trainee Projects\shopify\shopify++> node product.js

{"products":[]}
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: are you able to get the data from single product?

Comment: Make sure in admin area sample product are published and available for online store

Comment: I'm not sure about it, Could you tell me from where i can add sample store.

Comment: when you add the product to store, when you publish the product that need to avialble for online store sale channel, and also make sure when you create private app assign the required scope for product listing which are `read_products`, and `write_products`

Comment: I have included both of the scopes in configration. Still it is same case.

Comment: share what code you tried until, then able to say anything about it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364356/shopify-errors-api-this-action-requires-merchant-approval-for-write-themes

Comment: check here, as private apps are not supported now, so you need drop with URL scheme and get data with standtred auth using Admin API access token form private app

Comment: https://prnt.sc/-85l-800H313

Comment: what is the issue, is this token related?